# How to set the input value to be a object's property's value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set the input value to be a object's property's value,
here is the code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nba_jl/f9bt6c79/35/),
I also put the code here:
html

```
<div id="contenu"></div>
```

js

```
// create the button
var contenu = document.getElementById("contenu");
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.textContent = "add";
contenu.appendChild(btn);

// click the button to create 2 inputs and submit
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // create 2 inputs and submit
    var name = document.createElement("input");
    name.placeholder = "enter a name";
    var age = document.createElement("input");
    age.placeholder = "enter the age";
    var submit = document.createElement("input");
    submit.type = "submit";
    submit.value = "submit";
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "post";
    form.appendChild(name);
    form.appendChild(age);
    form.appendChild(submit);
    contenu.appendChild(form);

    // create a new empty table
    var newTable = [];
    var newObject = {};
    newObject.name = name.value;//"Tom" will work
    newObject.age = age.value;//20 will work
    newTable.push(newObject);

    // submit the form to show the input value in html
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        newTable.forEach(function(table){
            e.preventDefault();
            var pElt = document.createElement("p");
            pElt.innerHTML = table.name + " " + table.age;  
            contenu.appendChild(pElt);
        });   
    });
});
```

Objective: click the "add" button to show 2 inputs and the "submit" button, enter the name and the age, then click "submit" to show them in the `div`, I put the input's value as the property's value of the object, `newObject.name = name.value;` and `newObject.age = age.value;` but it dosen't work, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your fiddle, you can check it out here:

https://jsfiddle.net/o08mua1y/

```
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
        newObject.name = name.value;//"Tom" will work
        newObject.age = age.value;//20 will work
        newTable.forEach(function(table){
            e.preventDefault();
            var pElt = document.createElement("p");
            pElt.innerHTML = table.name + " " + table.age;  
            contenu.appendChild(pElt);
        });   
    });
```

The issue is that you are trying to set the value of the name, and age field in the listener that creates your input fields, not in the listener that fires on submission of the inputs. If you set those values inside the submit listener, before the forEach loop the values will be set, and be displayed in your HTML as intended

Comment: It works well! They're just not in the right place! If I want to set the value, it needs a trigger as you said, I understand now, thank you, your help is very useful for me!

Comment: Yep you've got it, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

`name` and `age` do not have a value at the time that you create the `newObject`. You need to attach an event listener like `keyup` or `keydown` or `change` to the input field to fire a function to set the values in the object.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it works when I set them into a eventListener, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you did there but this makes it work. Take a look.

```
// create de button
var contenu = document.getElementById("contenu");
var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.textContent = "add";
contenu.appendChild(btn);

// click the button to create 2 inputs and submit
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
// create 2 inputs and submit
var name = document.createElement("input");
name.placeholder = "enter a name";
var age = document.createElement("input");
age.placeholder = "enter the age";
var submit = document.createElement("input");
submit.type = "submit";
submit.value = "submit";
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.method = "post";
form.appendChild(name);
form.appendChild(age);
form.appendChild(submit);
contenu.appendChild(form);

// create a new empty table
var newTable = [];


// submit the form to show the input value in html
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  var newObject = {};
  newObject.name = name.value;//"Tom" will work
  newObject.age = age.value;//20 will work
  newTable.push(newObject);
  var pElt = document.createElement("p");
  pElt.innerHTML = newObject.name + " " + newObject.age;  
  contenu.appendChild(pElt);   
  e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: Your help is useful too, I'm learning javascript from a online course  "OpenClassroom.com", when I am stuck, no teacher, so I come here looking for help, thanks